# How should I report the origin of a word on English.SE?

Tags: discussion, answering-advice

When I report the origin of a word, how should I write the meaning of the word from which the word derives?

- I write it in quotes, after the word in that language: Latin *minister* "servant".
- I write it between parentheses: Latin *minister* (servant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no one right way to do it, but I prefer the second choice, although I also put the word in quotes even when it is in parentheses: *example* ("meaning").  I think the parentheses make it more clear than just having the meaning follow after the word.

A lot of dictionaries will use a more concise style, which I think is a holdover from when space considerations were important. Personally, I think we can afford the additional space if it gives more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. Perhaps I'd add a comma after *minister* in your first example. You could add additional quotation marks within the brackets in your second example, but that isn't necessary. I use both forms, though I think I have a slight preference for *minister*, "servant". I think this is the most standard option.

Comment: The first "style" is the one I see on the NOAD. I thought to add the comma after _minister_, but that doesn't seem to match the punctuation used in the sentence.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The word in quotation marks is best considered an apposition to the one in italics, and appositions are usually separated by commas.